# Is the set of languages over an alphabet Σ missing k words from Σ* countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability, formal-languages

My original question is whether $\mathscr{L}$, the set of all languages over an alphabet $Σ$, each of which missing finitely number of words from $Σ$* is countable. I think I can prove the set is countable by proving it is $\bigcup_{k=0}^{}S_k$ where each $S_k$ is the set of languages missing $k$ words from $Σ$*. Now, is there a way to prove each $S_k$ is countable? Is it enough to say each $S_k$ is also a union of subsets of $Σ$*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I meant the set of languages, each of which lacks finitely many words.

Comment: Does the answer answer your question? or does it assume something you still need to prove?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a little perplexed by this part "and conversely every cofinite set of integers $C$". Is it possible to show $\mathscr{L}$ is countable by showing it is an union of countable sets?

Comment: Oops it was missing the word "for". I fixed, it now reads: "and conversely for every cofinite set of integers $C$, $f(C)\in\mathscr{L}$". Does that clarify?

Comment: I guess not....

Comment: Thank you it makes sense now! One last bit, how did you prove there is a bijection between the set of cofinite sets of integers and finite sets of integers.

Comment: **That**'s easy — send every set to its complement! Obviously that's a bijection on $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$, but also clearly (yes?) it sends finite subsets to cofinite subsets, and vice versa.

Comment: (same bijection as in the 2nd and last paragraph, transferred to $\Bbb N$ from $\Sigma^*$. That's the easier approach, frankly: I assume you know that $\Sigma^*$ is countably infinite, and that the finite subsets of a countably infinite set form a countably infinite set.) ¶ PS — tips appreciated here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Fix a bijection $f\colon \Bbb N \to \Sigma^*$. ($\Sigma$ is finite, so there is such an $f$.) Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the class of all languages $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$ such that $\Sigma^*\setminus L$ is finite. Then for every $L\in \mathscr{L}$, $f^{-1}(L)$ is a cofinite subset of $\Bbb N$, and conversely for every cofinite set of integers $C$, $f(C)\in\mathscr{L}$. Thus, $\mathscr{L}$ is bijectable with the cofinite sets of integers, which are bijectable with the finite sets of integers. Finally, note that the set of finite sets of integers is countably infinite.

More directly, if $\mathscr{F}$ is the set of finite languages over $\Sigma$, then $L\mapsto (\Sigma\setminus L)$ bijects $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{L}$, and $\mathscr{F}$ is countable.

Comment: You are reading "missing finitely number of words" very differently from how I read it. The OP needs to clarify the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Ya, I saw your comment & thought.. ¿que? You're as a rule spot-on. How are you interpreting it? I agree that "missing $k$ words from $\Sigma$" is ... an unfortunate turn of phrase.

Comment: I read it as languages missing some given set of $k$ words, rather than languages whose complement has cardinality $k$.

Comment: @RobArthan Ahh, yes, quite different question, and answer. But now, seeing that OP defines $S_k$ for each $k$, and was considering their union, it seems he does mean "cofinite" after all.